# Cannot find module 'class-transformer' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: typescript, nestjs, class-transformer

I am trying to use the class-transformer package with NestJS v7. The class-transformer package was installed with `npm i class-transformer --save`. I've followed instructions as per [readme.md](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer)

This package does have a typescript definition, I can see it on my filesystem (in the correct directory inside node_modules), VS Code navigates to the definition just fine, so I am completely baffled why it isn't working. I've tried removing my node_modules directory, clearing my NPM cache and reinstalling everything again with `npm install`.

When I try to compile, I just get `Cannot find module 'class-transformer' or its corresponding type declarations.`

My entity code:

```
import {
    Column,
    Entity,
    Index,
    OneToMany,
    PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
} from "typeorm";
import { Expose } from 'class-transformer';

@Entity("country", { schema: "my_schema" })
export class Country {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({ type: "int", name: "id" })
    id: number;

    // Some properties here

    @Expose()
    get name(): string {
        return this.someProperty.content;
    }
    ...
}
```

My tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "sourceMap": false,
    "outDir": "./dist",
  }
}
```

My package.js:

```
{
  "name": "project-name",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "private": true,
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "scripts": {
    "prebuild": "rimraf dist",
    "build": "nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "nest start",
    "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "nest start --debug 0.0.0.0:9229 --watch",
    "start:prod": "node dist/main",
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^7.4.2",
    "@nestjs/config": "^0.5.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^7.0.0",
    "@nestjs/typeorm": "^7.1.0",
    "class-transformer": "^0.3.1",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.4",
    "typeorm": "^0.2.25"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cli": "^7.0.0",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^7.0.0",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^7.0.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.3",
    "@types/jest": "25.2.3",
    "@types/node": "^13.9.1",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.8",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "3.0.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "3.0.2",
    "eslint": "7.2.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.10.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.1",
    "jest": "26.0.1",
    "prettier": "^1.19.1",
    "supertest": "^4.0.2",
    "ts-jest": "26.1.0",
    "ts-loader": "^6.2.1",
    "ts-node": "^8.6.2",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^3.9.0",
    "typescript": "^3.7.4"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "testRegex": ".spec.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }
}
```

I've spent 2 frustrating hours trying to work out why this is the case. This is the only package I've had this kind of issues with, and looking at my config, the package itself and everything else, it makes no sense whatsoever to me.

Comment: What reports the error? Running `tsc`? What happens when you run `./node_modules/.bin/tsc --noemit`?

Comment: Hi. Running `npm run start:dev` reports the error. It's essentially an alias of `nest start --watch`. The [nestjs documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/serialization#serialization) specifically discusses using class-transformer, which is why I can't understand why this isn't working

Comment: Gotcha. I'm trying to figure out which tool is actually failing to resolve the file by first determining that your installed typescript can find it. These tools delegate to each other.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice the second part of your reply. Running `./node_modules/.bin/tsc --noemit` returns no errors

Comment: It sounds like nest isn't using `tsc` which could be a config issue because it's the default according to the [docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/cli/overview#project-structure). Try scaffolding a new empty project and see what's different. One thing I noticed was that you aren't specifying a `rootDir` just an `outDir`. Conventionally, your `rootDir` would be `src`.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: This issue has been fixed with the later releases, upgrade all packages, but keep class-transformer on version 0.3.1.